# My code isn't working although it uses correct syntax

Tags: php

My code isn't working although it conforms with PHP syntax.

```
$x=200;
$y=100;
class Human {
    public $numLegs=2;
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name=$name; // The PHP stops being parsed as PHP from the "->"
    }
    public function greet(){
        print "My name is $name and I am happy!"; // All of this is just written to the screen!
    }
}
$foo=new Human("foo");
$bar=new Human("bar");
$foo->greet();
$bar->greet();
echo "The program is done";
```

Why isn't it working?
This is literally the output, copy-pasted:

name=$name; } public function greet(){ print "My name is {this->$name} and I am happy!"; } } $foo=new Human("foo"); $bar=new Human("bar"); $foo->greet(); $bar->greet(); echo "The program is done"; ?>

Comment: what is it supposed to do?  Is it your substitution that is not working?  $name prints, instead of name?

Comment: That's unfortunate. So, what's your question?

Comment: It's supposed to make two Human objects but it doesn't work

Comment: I think it works, your just saying that $name prints?

Comment: @user2904527 Ok, so, what's your question?

Comment: No, it just writes all of the code instead of doing it

Comment: Just writes all of the code? As in you see the PHP on the page? Does your page have a .php extension?

Comment: So... you're missing `<?php` at the beginning?

Comment: No, i didn't put that here. It's in my code

Comment: Could it be your server does not suport php?  Are you viewing this page locally? (that wont work)

Answer (score 1):

When accessing properties of an object from inside the class's code you need to use `$this`. You accessing the `$name` property of `Human` from inside `greet()` but you are missing the `$this`.

It should be:

```
public function greet(){
    print "My name is {$this->name} and I am happy!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your PHP code with `<?php` to show that it is PHP code, not just plain text.

Its not valid syntax `$name` is not defined in this scope:

```
public function greet(){
    print "My name is $name and I am happy!"; // All of this is just written to the screen!
}
```

Since `$name` is a member of the class not the function you need to use `$this`

```
public function greet(){
    print "My name is {$this->name} and I am happy!"; // All of this is just written to the screen!
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... But thank you

Comment: @user2904527, i updated my answer, see Dan Lugg's answer as well. you need to start the page with `<?php`. The file extension also has to be .php not .html or anything else

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using name as a variable instead of a class members. You need to use the `$this` keyword.

```
 print "My name is $name and I am happy!";
```

by

```
 print "My name is $this->name and I am happy!";
```